# Warning while using gcc compiler -Wimplicit-int

Tags: c

I'm just starting out on C language and I'm getting stuck on a seemingly very basic code. Now, I'm using gcc to compile on ubuntu terminal and I keep getting this warning:

**return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]**

NOTE: the program compiles and runs just fine, but this warning bugs me. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

myFunction(char name[])

{    
    printf("Hello %s\n", name);
}

int main(void)
{
    myFunction("Liam")
    myFunction("John")
    myFunction("Anne")
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `myFunction(char name[])` --> `void myFunction(char name[])`

Comment: Please don't spam your post with tags, use only tags related to your question.

Comment: Did you try googling the error message?

Answer (score 1):

`myFunction(char name[])` is invalid C. In ancient days this syntax with no return type was allowed, the return type would then default to `int`. gcc kept this dangerous "feature" as a non-standard extension. Other compilers might just tell you that the program is invalid and refuse to generate an executable.

Change to:

```
void myFunction(char name[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `myFunction` does not declare any return types. If you do not specify any, C will assume you implicitly mean to return an int.

If you don't mean to return anything, you should declare it as `void myFunction`.

Comment: "If you do not specify any, C will assume you implicitly mean to return an int" Not since the previous millennium. If you don't specify a return type, you'll get a diagnostic message for writing invalid C.

Comment: @Lundin To be fair, it was allowed for 11 years this millenia ;)

Comment: @klutt No this was removed in C99 and likely deprecated before that.

Comment: @Lundin Fair enough. Then I remember wrong.